# Laravel boot deleting method slow

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, sql-delete

**code to trigger delete queue**

```
 DB::beginTransaction();
    $this->deleteid = [3, 8, 38, 72, 99, 9, 11, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 90, 41, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 71, 73, 100];
    foreach ($this->deleteid as $key => $value) {
    
     //delete player/player_tranasction/player_score/player_commision
     Player::where('parent_id', $value)->get()->each->delete();
    
    }
    
    DB::commit();
```

**Model**

```
//Player model

public function getTransaction()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(PlayerTransaction::class, 'player_id', 'id');
    }

    public static function boot() 
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::deleting(function($player) { // before delete() method call this
           $player->getTransaction()->get()->each->delete();
        });
    }

//player transaction table

public function transactionCommission()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(PlayerCommission::class, 'transaction_id', 'id');
    }

    public function transactionScore()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(PlayerScore::class, 'player_transaction_id', 'id');
    }

    public static function boot() 
    {
        parent::boot();
        
        static::deleting(function($playerTransaction) {
           $playerTransaction->transactionCommission()->delete();
           $playerTransaction->transactionScore()->delete();
        });
    }
```

**Question**: currently I create one delete queue function to delete the data based on the relationship method, it's working but will take more than 3 min to delete even timeout sometimes, the logic behind will be to retrieve the player delete id then perform to delete one by one. The data inside the database will have more than 600k. Does anyone have any idea to make it fast when delete, I really don't have an idea how to enhance it T.T.

```
Player -> parent_id
Player_transaction -> player_id
Player_commision -> player_transaction_id
Player_score -> player_transaction_id
```

Comment: If you have huge no of ```getTransaction``` relations it will take time.

Comment: First off, Why are you not using a ondelete cascade on the relation? second no need to loop over all the relations `$player->getTransaction()->delete();`

Comment: Hi @MichaelMano, the reason I use this to loop is need to trigger the boot deleting function in player_transaction model

Comment: Can Laravel generate `DELETE FROM tbl WHERE id IN (3, 8, 38, 72, 99, 9, 11, 15, 16, 17, ...)`?  That's the optimal way.

Answer (score 1):

You should use cascades for this.

Imagine you have the following tables

- A `users` table
- A `posts` table containing the foreign key `posts.user_id`

The desired behaviour is that when a `users` row is deleted, the associated `posts` rows get deleted too. You can accomplish this with a `delete cascade`.

You can define a `delete cascade` in Laravel whilst creating the migration. An example using my imaginary table structure would be:

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->cascadeOnDelete();
```